# How to build and use flink-connector-kinesis?

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, apache-flink, amazon-kinesis, connector

I'm trying to use Apache Flink with AWS kinesis. The [document](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/connectors/kinesis.html) says that I have to build the connector on my own.

Therefore, I build the connector and added the jar file for my project and also, I put the dependency on my pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-connector-kinesis_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version> 
</dependency>
```

However, when I tried to build using `mvn clean package` I got an error message like this

```
[INFO] -----------------------< kkaldk:flink-kinesis >-----------------------
[INFO] Building Flink Quickstart Job 0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.flink:flink-connector-kinesis_2.11:jar:1.6-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.458 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-19T17:45:43+09:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project flink-kinesis: Could not resolve dependencies for project kkaldk:flink-kinesis:jar:0.1: Failure to find org.apache.flink:flink-connector-kinesis_2.11:jar:1.6-SNAPSHOT in https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of apache.snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced -> 
[Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Could you help me to fix this?

---------added----------

This is what I've done (which is wrong procedure)

1. started project following this [document](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/projectsetup/java_api_quickstart.html)
2. build connector from [flink master source](https://github.com/apache/flink) (which is 1.8-snapshot)
3. add dependency with 1.6.1 version.

---

Comment: What did you put in your pom to add the kinesis jar file to your project?

Comment: @Arthur I added the code on my post.

Comment: So when you say you've added 'the jar file for my project', you mean you called this? `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=flink-connector-kinesis_2.10-1.6.1.jar -DpomFile=flink-connector-kinesis_2.10-1.6.1.pom.xml`? The difficulty here is that you trying to use a dependency that is not in the maven central repo. I think this link may help: http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/

Comment: @BumhwanKim how did you build and add the dependency of the conector you build? I also need to use the Kinesis conector but as they said [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/kinesis.html)

Comment: @IoTuser I've posted my solution below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is what I've done for solution.

1. I downloaded 1.6.1 release from [here](https://github.com/apache/flink/archive/release-1.6.1.zip).
2. unzip the file (the archive will be unzip in `.../flink-release-1.6.1/`
3. built it by `mvn clean install -Pinclude-kinesis -DskipTests`

Then I have flink-connector-kinesis_2.11 version 1.6.1 in my local maven repository

(for me, path was like this): `~/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-connector-kinesis_2.11`

After then, I could use this connector at any project by adding dependency with this code. (I don't have to add the jar file anymore.)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-connector-kinesis_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful

Comment: i have done the same steps and in my local repo it showing the connector jar exist in the below path 

org/apache/flink/flink-connector-kinesis_2.11/1.9.0/flink-connector-kinesis_2.11-1.9.0.jar.lastUpdated

But still my project is not able to build.i am getting below error

Could not resolve dependencies for project org.data.bounce:BounceProcessor:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.apache.flink:flink-connector-kinesis_2.11:jar:1.9.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository,

Comment: @Anujjain I am getting a very similar error, did you ever resolve this?