# Apache Flink with AWS Kinesis Analytics

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, intellij-idea, amazon-kinesis

> The actual situation

I want to use Apache Flink with Kinesis Analytics. Like I don't have experience with Java and Maven and going to try to summary the steps I followed and the results.

1. Use IntelliJ IDEA as IDE
2. Test this [example](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/tutorials/datastream_api.html#writing-a-flink-program) without any problems
3. Change to AWS, following their [instruction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/java/get-started-exercise.html#get-started-exercise-5). The problems start in the step: *Create and Compile the Apache Flink Streaming Java Code*

---

**The problems**

If you want to use the Kinesis connector, you can not do it like other connector due to the ASL license and they do not deploy the artifact to the Maven central repository on Flink releases, so you will need to build the Kinesis connector by yourself download the source code for the connector from here [Apache Flink](https://github.com/apache/flink), and install it to your local Maven repository.

After download it, you have build the module following this [steps](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/kinesis.html):

```
mvn clean install -Pinclude-kinesis -DskipTests
```

So I move to the unziped folder, and run the mvn command, with this error:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 50.670 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-27T14:35:13+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.rat:apache-rat-plugin:0.12:check (default) on project flink-parent: Too many files with unapproved license: 2 See RAT report in: C:\Users\...\flink-master\target\rat.txt -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :flink-parent
```

Trying to find a solution, I tried what this user said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30184248/10346701)

```
mvn clean install -Pinclude-kinesis -DskipTests  -Drat.ignoreErrors=true package
```

But again, I had an error:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:15 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-27T14:40:47+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project flink-shaded-hadoop2: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-hadoop2:jar:1.8-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.6 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11/../lib/tools.jar -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :flink-shaded-hadoop2
```

---

> The questions

1. **How should I build the connector module?**
2. **How should I install it to my local Maven repository?**

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53996699/10346701) you could find how to build the kinesis conector

Answer (score 2):

After receiving similar errors, even after using the other answer's solution for checking out a release branch, I found a solution that works for me. According to the [build guide](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/flinkDev/building.html) in the Flink docs, you can also add the `-Dfast` option to speed up build time. In my case, this resolved the licensing errors:

```
mvn clean install -Pinclude-kinesis -DskipTests -Dfast
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you're trying to build the "snapshot" build of the Flink connector, not the release build.

Since you're not familiar with Java and Maven, here's what that means: Maven differentiates between "snapshot" builds, which are currently under active development, and "release" builds. Normally a project only pushes its release builds to Maven Central. However, for long-running development, the "master" branch is often a snapshot.

The POM in your linked instructions references version 1.6.2, so that's what you should be building. Check out the tag `release-1.6.2`, and also make sure that you're reading the Flink documentation for that version (your link above is for the latest development version).